# how to insert current date into a DATE field in dd/mm/yyyy format in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, date-format

I have a field in my table with datatype as DATE in Oracle.
I want to insert the current date into that field, in format DD/MM/YYYY format.

I tried the below query:

```
select to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual
```

But it gives

```
1/8/2011 12:00:00 AM.
```

I want it to insert and show as

```
08/01/2011 12:00:00 AM.
```

Can anyone help me in this please ?

Comment: *Presentation* of a date has numerous formats; requiring a specific one that is not the default is better handled either at the very last moment the date is returned from the database, or in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DATE` is a built-in type in Oracle, which is represented in a fixed way and you have no control over it.

So:

> I want it to insert [...] as 08/01/2011 12:00:00 AM

The above is nonsensical. You don't insert a string, you insert a date.

Format is useful only when you want:

- to convert a string to an internal representation of date with `TO_DATE` (format mask: how to parse the string);
- to convert an internal representation of date to a string with `TO_CHAR` (format mask: how to render the date).

So basically, in your example you take a DATE, you convert it to a STRING with some format, and convert it back to DATE with the same format. This is a no-op.

Now, what your client displays: this is because your Oracle Client won't display DATE fields directly and the NLS layer will convert any DATE field that is selected. So it depends on your locale by default.

What you want is `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM dual;` which will explicitly perform the conversion and return a string.

And when you want to insert a date in a database, you can use `TO_DATE` or date literals.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you want to retrieve the date part of the DATE field, you may use truncate, i.e.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate),'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;
```

Comment: `TRUNC` is unnecessary if you're formatting the date to be without the time portion.

Answer (score 1):

When the column is of type DATE, you can use something like:

```
Insert into your_table(your_date_column) Select TRUNC(SYSDATE) from DUAL;
```

This removes the time part from SYSDATE.

Comment: -1: No, TRUNC does *not* remove the time portion -- **TRUNC sets the time portion to be at midnight** for that date.

Comment: @OMG Thanks for technical details. Is that a linguistic problem? In Germany you would be called a **Erbsenzähler**, as everybody in the buisiness knows that removing the time part means set the time part to '00:00'.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this can help

```
insert into pasok values ('&kode_pasok','&kode_barang','&kode_suplier',
to_date('&tanggal_pasok','dd-mm-yyyy'),&jumlah_pasok);
```

> note: '&' help we to insert data again, insert / end than enter to
>   insert again example: Enter value for kode_pembelian: BEL-E005 Enter
>   value for kode_barang: ELK-02 Enter value for kode_customer: B-0001
>   old   2: '&kode_pembelian','&kode_barang','&kode_customer', new   2:
>   'BEL-E005','ELK-02','B-0001', Enter value for tanggal_pembelian:
>   24-06-2002 Enter value for jumlah_pembelian: 2 old   3:
>   to_date('&tanggal_pembelian','dd-mm-yyyy'),&jumlah_pembelian) new   3:
>   to_date('24-06-2002','dd-mm-yyyy'),2)
>
> 1 row created.
>
> SQL> / (enter)