# Oracle: How to convert the following date to a different format:

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

in my select query i have the following

```
substr(to_date(NEXT_ARRIVAL_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 0, 10)
```

Which yields:

```
08-JUN-11
```

What i need is it to yield:

`2011-06-08`

EDIT: 
The data was coming in wrong. sorry. The below workds fine

```
to_char(to_date(NEXT_ARRIVAL_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') ||  ' 00:000:00'
```

Comment: Your formatting appears correct, are you sure that is the output you are getting?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633271/how-to-insert-current-date-into-a-date-field-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-oracle/4633292#4633292)

Comment: What data type is NEXT_ARRIVAL_DATE - is it a date or a string?

Answer (score 3):

Your DATE_NEXT_ARRIVAL column obviously has a date datatype.

```
SQL> create table t23 (next_arrival_date date)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into t23 values (sysdate+7)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> select to_date(next_arrival_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  2  from t23
  3  /

TO_DATE(N
---------
11-JUN-08

SQL>
```

If you want to display the date in a different format you need to use `TO_CHAR()` i.e. convert it to a string:

```
SQL> select to_char(next_arrival_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  2  from t23
  3  /

TO_CHAR(NE
----------
2011-06-08

SQL>
```

If you have to do this for a whole bunch of dates, you might want to change the session settings instead....

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD'
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate, next_arrival_date
  2  from t23
  3  /

SYSDATE    NEXT_ARRIV
---------- ----------
2011-06-01 2011-06-08

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

in Oracle you can convert a DATE column to string with

```
to_char(NEXT_ARRIVAL_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

but it looks like the value of NEXT_ARRIVAL_DATE is a string in the required format.
so you can just do `select NEXT_ARRIVAL_DATE from ...`