# How to Insert a date field with format ("MM/dd/yyyy") in Detailview?

Tags: asp.net, .net, datetime

I'm trying to insert date with "MM/dd/yyyy" Format into a date format field in a detailed view. But I am gettin error Message:

```
 String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

I tried Like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("RenewalDate","{0,MM/dd/yyyy}")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I insert date with format MM/dd/yyyy????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633271/how-to-insert-current-date-into-a-date-field-in-dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format string is invalid. You need a colon after the placeholder instead of a comma:

```
Text='<%# Bind("RenewalDate","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")%>'
```

That should fix the problem, assuming `RenewalDate` is a `DateTime` column. If it isn't a `DateTime` column, you'll need to convert it before you apply the format:

```
Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Bind("RenewalDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") %>'
```

**EDIT**

To ensure that the input is valid, you can add compare and required field validators:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqDateValidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" />
<asp:CompareValidator
    id="dateValidator" runat="server" 
    Type="Date"
    Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Date">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: Hi, I am sry I typed it wrong on the post. But I tried with correct syntax but I am getting the same error. And just for the clarification, is this a correct way to insert data? coz I am not displaying the data I am inserting data.

Comment: Yes renewalDate is a dateTime filed.

Comment: See the second example then. Unless something is really out of whack, the second example should definitely work. It's tough to tell whether or not your inserting correctly from the example you provided. I would need more context to answer that question.

Comment: I follwed the first example of yours and it let me insert with the format dd/MM/yyyy, but When I enter date with the format MM/dd/yyyy it show the same error.

Comment: using Eval will loose two way binding.

Comment: Your scenario doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Can you post your insert logic too? Are you converting it back to a `DateTime` before inserting it?

Comment: @PankajGarg: Thanks. Didn't mean to use `Eval`.

Comment: @JamesJohnson No I use sql datasource, So apparently It creates everything. I just used the wizard.

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` is giving crash in case the date value is not valid.

Comment: @PankajGarg: There are numerous ways around that. My answer is intended to demonstrate a concept, not a finished product. It's moot anyway though since the column is a `DateTime` type.

Comment: But this is not an answer to a question. This answer is not useful for future users. The question is explicitly saying conversion error and there is nothing special provided to fix it.

Comment: I suggest you read the question and the comments. There was a conversion error, but the column is a `DateTime` type. OP was receiving this error performing the insert, which can be negated with proper validation.

Answer (score 0):

you `RenewalDate` being imported from the DB is **not** a valid `DateTime` object.

otherwise - it wont show you this error.

show the Query for which you get the value.

Comment: if I insert like "2012-04-04" (yyyy-mm-dd) it let me insert. The deatil view doesn't understand the format MM/dd/yyyy that's the prob. But I need to insert date in MM/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: again, you arent returning datetime OBJECT from DB/DataSource. if you have a string value instead of DateTime value you should use `DateTime.TryParse ` function