# Entity Framework save DateTime without time to oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, odp.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project that interacts with an oracle 10g database through ODP.net (Oracle Data Provider) with a database first approach with an edmx file mapping the DB.

I need to save various "date" fields on the oracle DB, some with the date portion, some with a full timestamp (date/time).

I WANT to do this avoiding triggers and db interventions.

I managed to save only full timestamps.

How I can save only the date part?

I've tried to pass DateTime.Date, DateTime.Today But nothing.

I've tried to set default into the edmx files but it still saves a full timestamp.

I've tried to manually edit the edmx storage model through the xml editor and setting a default to the DB mapped fields (tried SYSDATE and all you can think).

Nothing it's working.

Do I really have to do something gross like a trigger or a programmatic SQL update with a SQLCommand (bypassing the EF and launching sql commands in the ADO.net style) after the insert to correcly format the data?

There isn't a way to do this with entity framework?

Comment: I think `Date` datatype is supposed to work that.[Read More Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4633292/2196341)

Comment: You do realize in Oracle you can't save "only the date part", right? Perhaps you mean "save a date, with the time portion set to 00:00:00"? In that case, `trunc(sysdate)` is what you seem to need.

Comment: @mathguy Or `DateTime.Today` when set from C# code.